# when adapter consume memory in list-view either setting adapter to listview or setting values to the adapter

Tags: android

I have a list adapter

```
adapter = new SimpleCardStackAdapter(this);

       // System.gc(); i should call this function here or just before set adapter calling
        int i=0;
        if(cardModels.size() > VISIBLE_NUMBER_OF_CARDS){
            i = cardModels.size()-VISIBLE_NUMBER_OF_CARDS;
        }
        for ( ;i < cardModels.size(); i++) {
            //if(i<VISIBLE_NUMBER_OF_CARDS){
            adapter.add(cardModels.get(i));
            //}else{
            //    break;
            //}
        }

 // System.gc(); i should call this function or here 
        mCardContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my question is when adapter consume memory 
during setadapter or during creating adapter

i m facing out of memory error ... adapter items has some large bitmaps 
i have to call manually garbage collector before memory consuming operation will happen thanks.

Comment: I think you have to efficiently handle your bitmaps instead of manually start the garbage collector.

Comment: i know this is not recommended .... i tried .... but was not successfull ... this problem comes with low memory devices .... so i have to do

Comment: Memory allocates when you initialize your objects.

Comment: means when we created the adapter only it will allocate memory @Piyush Gupta

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to get the bitmap in correspondence to the size of your imageview where you want to load them...this can help prevent creating large bitmaps for smaller imageviews even..

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String filepath,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
```

}